# Page Curl(flipping) in CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, page-curl

I already succeeded in making a page curl in JavaScript but its a little slow,
can i make page flipping in pure CSS?

This is a small snippet of the code

```
    function drawFlip( flip ) {
    // Strength of the fold is strongest in the middle of the book
    var strength = 1 - Math.abs( flip.progress );

    // Width of the folded paper
    var foldWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.165 ) * ( 1 - flip.progress/0.5 );

    // X position of the folded paper
    var foldX = PAGE_WIDTH * flip.progress + foldWidth;

    // How far the page should outdent vertically due to perspective
    var verticalOutdent = 20 * strength;

    // The maximum width of the left and right side shadows
    var paperShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( 1 - flip.progress, 0.5 ), 0 );
    var rightShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( strength, 0.5 ), 0 );
    var leftShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( strength, 0.5 ), 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is CSS3 Page flip http://romancortes.com/ficheros/page-flip.html

Comment: Thanks alot but i want to perform the flipping on (on-click) event and drag the page to open it.